# Find four natural numbers with a certain property

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can we find four natural numbers $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $T$, greater than 1 and different from each other, so that adding 1 to the product of any three of them, the sum is divisible by the fourth?

Comment: Is there a reason for the mismatch between question title and content, and for the metric-geometry and classical-analysis-and-odes tags (and probably the algebraic-geometry and prime-numbers tags as well)?

Comment: True, but the question is interesting even so

Comment: @GHfromMO I may be missing something, but I don't see how that satisfies the question; $XYZ + 1 = 232$, which is not divisible by $T = 15$.

Comment: @user44191 Sorry, I misread the last word as "four".

Comment: It might be possible to find all such quadruples. $XYZT \mid XYZ + XYT + XZT + YZT + 1$ and  number $1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z + 1/T + 1/(XYZT)$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @DenisShatrov That does limit it pretty heavily; the sum of five distinct integer reciprocals can only be an integer if either a) one of them is $1$, or b) the sum is exactly $1$, as $H_6 = \frac{59}{20} < 3$.

Comment: Can one find a set of natural numbers for which multiplying finitely many members and adding $1$ always yields a number divisible by some member of the set? Certainly the set of all primes does that. Does it have a proper subset that does that? In the posted answer, $\{\,2,3,7,43\,\}$ the product of any three, plus one, is divisible by the fourth AND the product of any two, plus one, is divisible by one of the other two. But $2\times7+1$ is divisible not only by $3$ but also by a number coprime to all four members of this set. And similarly $2\times43+1, \,\,\, 3\times43+1,$ and $3\times7+1.$

Comment: In fact, the solution below is the only one where no variable is $1$. It's not hard to check that for $(3, 4, 5, 6)$ the sum is less than $1$, so the smallest variable must be $2$; then with the other variables being odd, the sum for $(2, 5, 7, 9)$ is less than $1$, so the second smallest must be $3$; the sum for $(2, 3, 5)$ is too large, so the third smallest must be at least $7$. It also must be less than $18$, and manual checking shows that $(2, 3, 7, 43)$ is the only possibility.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, you made my knowledge more complete. Now I'm just trying to demonstrate thate (2,3,7,43) is di only solution

Comment: @AndreaLanzillo It's the only solution if you assume $X, Y, Z, T > 1$; otherwise, $(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3)$, and $(1, 2, 3, 7)$ all work. I haven't checked extremely closely, but I'm pretty sure similar reasoning to the above will work.

Answer (score 5):

For four numbers, $2$, $3$, $7$ and $43$ do the job. In general, if $n$ is the amount of numbers and the product of all but one of them, say $T$, must be $-1$ modulo $T$, we can state the following:

1. All numbers must be coprime to each other. For if not, take one of a pair that is not coprime. The product of the rest is not $-1$ modulo that number because then it would be coprime to that number.
2. There is a combination of $n+1$ numbers with the same property by adding the product of all plus one. Since any product of $n$ of the combination containing this new number is still $-1$ modulo the missing number.
3. Therefore each instance of such a combination leads to an infinite chain of such combinations.

Starting with $2$ is obvious since it equals the empty product plus one.